# Why SQLAlchemy Session.filter().update/delete raise read-only exception when using RoutingSession?

Tags: python, mysql, session, sqlalchemy, master-slave

The following is my config, slave is read-only:

```
engines = {                                                                        
    'master': create_engine(                                                       
        settings.MASTER_URL, echo=settings.ECHO_SQL, pool_recycle=3600),           
    'slave': create_engine(                                                        
        settings.SLAVE_URL, echo=settings.ECHO_SQL, pool_recycle=3600),            
}                                                                                  


class RoutingSession(Session):                                                     
    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):                                  
        #return engines['master']                                                  
        if self._flushing:                                                         
            return engines['master']                                               
        else:                                                                      
            return engines['slave']                                                

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(class_=RoutingSession))
```

When I do :

```
s = DBSession()
#synchronize_session=False makes execution faster
s.query(Model).filter(Model.id == 1).delete(synchronize_session=False)
s.commit()
```

it raises an exception that it couldn't delete because of "read-only".

**How to rewrite my RoutingSession to make the above 'delete' use 'master' database**

---Edit1---

I've done more test. The above 'delete' is different from the following 'delete' which RoutingSession will return 'master':

```
model = s.query(Model).filter(Model.id == 1).first()
s.delete(model)
s.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

A `query.delete()` is not part of a "flush", so typically if you're using the [routing session recipe](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/01/11/django-style-database-routers-in-sqlalchemy/), you want to implement `using_bind()` and call upon that before an operation like a `delete()`:

```
class RoutingSession(Session):

    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None ):
        if self._name:
            return engines[self._name]
        else:
            # other cases here

    _name = None
    def using_bind(self, name):
        s = RoutingSession()
        vars(s).update(vars(self))
        s._name = name
        return s
```

then to use:

```
Session().using_bind("master").query(Model1).delete()
```